# Nodejs cannot Read and Write simultaneously

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, get

I am currently trying to develop a NodeJS application, which contains 3 main Routes:

```
app.get('/1',(req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './index.html'))
});

app.post('/1',(req, res) => {
model.sharetime(req.body.zeit);
});
```

and

```
app.get('/receive', (req, res) => {
res.json(model.receivetime());
});
```

The post Route /1 will be called once ever second, which receives a value that is put into an array.

The problem that I encounter is, each time I want to call the route /receive while the /1 get route is open, there is no response whatsoever,

after I restart the server, suddenly I get the response that I requested.

Which basically means, I cant have the route /1 which opens my index file open which I need for the application to post results back to the server and simultaneously receive the updated values via the route /receive.

Please help :)

Comment: You don't ever respond to the POST /1 - that might be the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much  :)
That was the mistake, works perfectly fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not responding to the request, you're merely calling a function with a value from the posted form. Add at least a `res.end();` to that route handler.

Comment: When I close the request with res.end(); the index.html will never loads. And I cant see it in the browser.

Comment: Did you add it to to the correct route handler? I was referring to the `app.post('/1', ...)` handler.

Comment: I am sorry, I misread what you said. 

It worked thank you :)